# Addon-Plugins are not loading on first run of the upgraded Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

In our addon we have two plugins and we noticed Firefox is not loading those 
plugins on first run after Firefox upgrade(eg: from 4.0.1 to 5.0). We noticed plugins are loading if we 
fire "about:plugins" on first run. 
What I am doing wrong here? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen with any plugins or just the ones you've developed? If it's an issue with all plugins (but only when packaged in an add-on), [file a bug report](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Bug_writing_guidelines), then try to get someone in #developers on irc.mozilla.org or mozilla.dev.platform to look into it.

Comment: @m m: Don't forget to mention if it's specific to any specific plugins (do you have to package 2 of them to reproduce the issue?) and to try and get someone to look at it once you provide all the information. It won't get a fast reply before the right developer sees it.

Comment: Given a sample xpi with the npruntime plugin distributed with Mozilla source.